# How to remove the status bar from CKeditor?

Tags: wysiwyg

It seems that the module [CKeditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) doesn't offer in the UI the option to remove the status bar which includes the HTML path (eg: `body p strong`) and the re-size button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to remove the status bar for a profile (`admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/some_profile`) by adding this code in **Advanced Settings** > **‏Custom JavaScript configuration ‏**:

```
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
config.resize_enabled = false;
```

Code found [here](http://ckeditor.com/comment/42512#comment-42512) on the CKeditor forum.