# Enabling text editor on statuses form

Tags: 7, forms, wysiwyg

I was looking to use a text editor with [statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses). Statuses is neither a Node nor an Entity. I searched a lot and found a simple solution. I just has to replace `'#type' => 'textarea',` with `'#type' => 'text_format',` in statuses/includes/utitlity/[statuses.form.inc](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1gf5j51n7jbo81/statuses.form.inc?dl=0) file. It converted it to a text format enabled textarea, **but there are few problems**.

1. Ckeditor is not respecting the character limit set by the module, so I found [maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength) module and added `'#maxlength_js' => TRUE,` but it does not make the default work. Instead it adds a separate character counter. The markitup library is respecting this, but I want to use ckeditor as I think it is the best editor. **How to overcome it?**
2. The form is now scrollable after enabling ckeditor. I want to disable scrolling. The resizeable was already set to FALSE in the module, but ckeditor is not respecting it. **How to solve it?**
3. How to hide paragraph counter and word counter? I have not enabled it from settings. I was there by default.

Here is the SnapShot of the statuses form.

[image]

Code was added like this: Only 2 modifications were made to the code, the rest is the original code of the module.

```
$form['fbss-status'] = array(
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#rows' => variable_get('statuses_box_rows', 2),
    '#maxlength_js' => TRUE,
    '#maxlength' => 140,
    // 508 compliance: add a label, but visually hide it
    '#title' => t('Status'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#default_value' => $default,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('statuses-text', 'statuses-text-main')),
    '#resizable' => FALSE,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="statuses-textarea-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#weight' => -40,
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your 2nd and 3rd questions, you could try this answer here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/62407/12701

Instead of hacking the statuses module, you should create your own module and use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 * Adding WYSIWYG editor to statuses
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'statuses_box':
      $form['fbss-status']['#type'] = 'text_format';
      $form['fbss-status']['#format'] = 'filtered_html';
      break;
    case 'fbss_comments_edit':
      $form['status-comment-edit']['#type'] = 'text_format';
      $form['status-comment-edit']['#format'] = 'filtered_html';
      break;
  }
  if (substr($form_id, 0, strlen('fbss_comments_box')) === 'fbss_comments_box') {
    $form['status-comment']['#type'] = 'text_format';
    $form['status-comment']['#format'] = 'filtered_html';
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code worked perfectly. How I can attach a user field with this form? It is a link field and I will be using oembed formatter for this field. When user shares the link with statuses, it will be converted to oembed. Then I will create a list of statuses containing these links via views. Currently, I have oembed filter enabled in one of text formats but this way I cannot show it in views.