# Add custom config to ckeditor

Tags: 8

I'd like to customise the CKEditor config, by using the [removePlugins](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-removePlugins) setting to disable the *elementspath* plugin, so that `body p` etc. isn't displayed in the status bar ([here's a similar, old question for D7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62406/how-to-remove-the-status-bar-from-ckeditor)).

I created the following CKEditor plugin, which returns an additional setting via the getConfig() method.  It has no effect on my editor fields (I've verified the plugin ID is being matched).

What's the right approach - if not this - for a config change, given I'm not loading a new plugin JS file or adding buttons?

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Definition of \Drupal\ckeditor_remove_elementspath\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin\RemoveElementsPath
 */

namespace Drupal\ckeditor_remove_elementspath\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin;

use Drupal\ckeditor\CKEditorPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Plugin\PluginBase;
use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;

/**
 * Defines the "Remove Elements Path" plugin.
 *
 * @CKEditorPlugin(
 *   id = "remove_elements_path",
 *   label = @Translation("Remove elements path"),
 *   module = "ckeditor_remove_elementspath"
 * )
 */
class RemoveElementsPath extends Pluginbase implements CKEditorPluginInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  function getDependencies(Editor $editor) {
    return [];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  function getLibraries(Editor $editor) {
    return [];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function isInternal() {
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFile() {
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getButtons() {
    return [ ];
  }

  public function getConfig(Editor $editor) {
    return [
      'removePlugins' => 'elementspath',
    ];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the [CKEditor API docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/ckeditor-api/overview) and the other classes I might extend - it didn't seem to be any of:

- `CKEditorPluginButtonsInterface`
- `CKEditorPluginContextualInterface`
- `CKEditorPluginCssInterface`

…though perhaps `CKEditorPluginConfigurableInterface`, if I wanted to configure the settings form per text format?

*Then*, I found a module called [ckeditor_config](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_config), so I adapted [it's plugin class](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/ckeditor_config/tree/src/Plugin/CKEditorPlugin/CustomConfig.php?h=8.x-1.x), which extends `CKEditorPlugin/Internal`:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Definition of \Drupal\ckeditor_remove_elementspath\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin\RemoveElementsPath
 */

namespace Drupal\ckeditor_remove_elementspath\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin;

use Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPlugin\Internal;
use Drupal\editor\Entity\Editor;

/**
 * Defines the "Remove Elements Path" plugin.
 *
 * @CKEditorPlugin(
 *   id = "remove_elements_path",
 *   label = @Translation("Remove elements path from CKEditor status bar")
 * )
 */
class RemoveElementsPath extends Internal {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getConfig(Editor $editor) {
    // Get default config.
    $config = parent::getConfig($editor);

    $config['removePlugins'] = 'elementspath';

    return $config;
  }

}
```

**Edit:** And [here's my module](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/wturrell/3018599) if anyone finds it useful.